# 400 bad request while passing object and value to url

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, spring, spring-mvc

I know how to pass data in url in json or with plain parameters but this is something different

see the below image :-

http://www.tiikoni.com/tis/view/?id=23d9b98

My api Url /geniedoc/api/doctor/Search

as we can see one thing is in object and two paramater is simply passing

can you suggest me a ajax call?

my ajax call

```
function getNewSlotContent(startIndex, totalRows) {
    var skipindex = 0;
    if (startIndex > 1) {
        skipindex = totalRows;
    }
    var totalrows = totalRows + 10;
    var searchByName = document.getElementById("searchByName").value;
    var selectedSpeciality = document.getElementById("searchByName").value;
    if (selectedSpeciality != null || selectedSpeciality != "") {
        selectedSpeciality = encodeURIComponent(selectedSpeciality);
    }
    $("#preloader").addClass("pageload");
    $("#preloader").show();

       var dataString = '{"firstName":"'+ searchByName + '","start_index":"' + skipindex + '","rows":"' + totalrows +'"}';

      console.log(dataString); 
    $.ajax({
         type: 'POST',
         url : '/geniedoc/api/doctor/search',
         data: dataString,
         contentType: 'application/json',
         dataType: 'json',
         headers: {'Content-Type':'application/json'}, 
        timeout: 100000,
        success: function(data) {
            var op = "";
            for (doctor in data.response.rows) {
                op += '<div class="post-sec">';
                op += '<a href=""><img src="/geniedoc/ajax/data/displayImage?fileName=' + data.response.rows[doctor].profilePicId + '" alt=""></a>';
                if (data.response.rows[doctor].prefix == null) {
                    data.response.rows[doctor].prefix = "";
                }
                op += '<a target="_blank" href="/doctor/' + data.response.rows[doctor].seo_name + '/' + data.response.rows[doctor].idKey + '" class="title"> ' + data.response.rows[doctor].prefix + ' ' + data.response.rows[doctor].firstame + ' ' + data.response.rows[doctor].last_name + '</a>';
                op += '<span class="date">' + data.response.rows[doctor].speciality_id + '</span>';
                op += '</div>';
                op += '<div class="clear"></div>';
            }
            $("#preloader").hide();
            $("#preloader").removeClass("pageload");
            $("#doctor-data").html(op);
        },
        error: function(e) {
            console.log("ERROR: ", e);
        },
        done: function(e) {
            console.log("DONE");
        }
    });
```

}

Comment: Your question seems to ask how to make an ajax call, which is too generic. If you have a specific issue, please provide relevant code and examples with sample output and data you have currently available. Please avoid external links. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Modify your dataString like this :

```
var dataString = {
"firstName":searchByName,
"start_index": skipindex,
"rows":  totalrows 
};
```